# Differential equation with gaussian noise MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics

The equation has the following form:

```
x'' + w.^2 x=n
w=1
```

and `n` is *Gaussian noise*  with `mean = 0` and `standard deviation = 1`.

Without the *Gaussian noise* I can solve the equation by using `ODE45` from `matlab`.The problem is, how can I deal with this equation when the Gaussian noise is taken into consideration?

Comment: Your question is ill-posed; x is presumably a function of some parameter t, so that x'' = d^2 x / dt^2.  Assuming that n is not just a constant, it must be a function of time.  There are multiple answers to exactly what 'Gaussian noise' means in a continuous time scenario, but these are questions better addressed in a math-themed context.  Please consider posting to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Usually, you need to know more about the noise than merely that it is Gaussian.  You need to know its *spectrum,* too; and even then your question is not easy.  Such noise is represented as the fine limit of a summation that, perplexingly, never converges to an integration.  (And if that didn't make sense to you, it only means that you're a normal person, because it wouldn't make sense to very many other people, either.  I am regrettably unable to explain in depth at a Stackoverflow length of a few paragraphs.)

Comment: You will want to do some reading on the topic of "stochastic differential equations", which is entirely inappropriate for this site. You might try math.stackexchange.com as suggested above.

Comment: If you just want noise for noise's sake `ode45` is fine. But if you want noise with a specific distribution and a solution that correctly corresponds to this, then you need to think in terms of SDEs and the Euler-Maruyama method, not ODEs. Read [this paper](http://www.caam.rice.edu/~cox/stoch/dhigham.pdf) (PDF) which includes Matlab examples. The code is out of date and not written for performance so you might try `sde_euler` in my [SDETools](https://github.com/horchler/SDETools) Matlab toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

it really depends on how the noise is added to the system. If you want to arbitrarily add noise to the system, in which every time the function is called, you add it to the equation representing your data:

```
function dydt = solve(t,y)
dydt = [y(2); -y(1)+randn(1)];
```

then call

```
[t,y] = ode45(@solve, [0 10],[1 -1]);
```

the problem here is that if the noise is large compared to the signal size, more iterations will be needed thus more time.

On the other hand, if the noise is predetermined, you can either sample and hold, or incorporate a first-order hold and then add that to the system

Comment: Yes i want to add the noise every time the function is called. The noise will be added to every point. For one trajectory, the ODE solver works but it became unstable for larger number of solution..how can i solve differential equation in MATLAB other than using ODE solver?

Comment: The ideal solution depends on what you're trying to solve. if you're more interested in brownian-like motion, ode45 is a horrible solver for your purposes, and you're better off using a fixed-step technique like Euler's or Runge-Kutta's method. For a general note, see this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1500/1510.html#stiff) and [here](http://www.cs.clemson.edu/~steve/CPLSCMODS/SDE-matlab/algfiles.html)

Comment: @Axell if you download ode5.m from the first link, you can call the following equation: `y = ode5(@khal,0:0.001:60',[0 0]);`, then `plot (0:0.001:60,y)`

Comment: I can solve first order ODE using Runge-Kutta's method but i am stuck with second order..after reduced the equation into two first order equations, do i have to solve them both simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, Always, as they usually are interrelated